# How to plot a circle in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, equation, figure

I would like to know how can I graph circles in Matlab knowing the center and radius? I have tried `circles()` which does not seem to work because my Matlab version does not have it. I know I can use the Rectangle function to do so but it is a rather complex way of doing it as I would need to work out the leftmost point everytime.

Isn't there a more simple way for me to draw a circle JUST knowing center and radius?

Comment: Yes, there surely is -- but you're not telling us about which plot type you're using. You can most likely just use discrete x,y coordinates that you'd get using r*sin(theta), r* cos(theta), theta in 0, 2pi.

Comment: are you able to show me /write what you mean? @MarcusMüller

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't laugh, but the easiest would be to use the [**`rectangle`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) function, indeed ;)

```
%// radius
r = 2;

%// center
c = [3 3];

pos = [c-r 2*r 2*r];
rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1])
axis equal
```

but set the curvature of the rectangle to **1**!

The `position` vector defines the rectangle, the first two values `x` and `y` are the lower left corner of the rectangle. The last two values define width and height of the rectangle.

```
pos = [ [x y] width height ]
```

The lower left *corner* of your circle - yes, this circle has corners, imaginary ones though - is the **center** `c = [3 3]` **minus the radius** `r = 2` which is `[x y] = [1 1]`. **Width** and **height** are equal to the **diameter** of the circle, so `width = 2*r; height = width;`

[image]

---

In case you don't like the smoothness of the above solution, there is no way around using the obvious way of drawing an actual circle by use of **trigonometric functions**.

```
%// number of points
n = 1000;

%// running variable
t = linspace(0,2*pi,n);

x = c(1) + r*sin(t);
y = c(2) + r*cos(t);

%// draw line
line(x,y)

%// or draw polygon if you want to fill it with color
%// fill(x,y,[1,1,1])
axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: great! could you explain what is the purpose of 2*r 2*r ? @thewaywewalk

Comment: well you want to draw a circle with a given radius. But your *"rectangle-circle"* is defined by the diameter which is **d = 2*r**

Comment: @thewaywewalk is it a circular rectangle or a rectangle circle? ;) Awesome!

Comment: @Shai, I don't know, but I promise to do some research.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to increase the number of points? The result looks polygon-y to me.

Comment: That's actually really funny. +1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a circle that is not [rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194105/1714410) you can use [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html)

```
center = [3, 4];
r = 2;
pos = [center-r, 2*r 2*r];
annotation('ellipse', pos );
```

Comment: How is this actually supposed to work? How it is, I get an error, because the default unit is *normalized* and the values of pos must be smaller 1. But I can't think of another setting of units, where it actually fits to the axes.

Comment: `annotation`'s use the figure coordinates, instead of the axis coordinates