# Circle in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I Was making real time interface between MATLAB and Ascention Trakstar (Motion) Sensor. In this task, I was display real time sensor position  as a square on MATLAB GUI figure window(Full Size of Screen).

I want to display sensor position on various shapes (Now focus on circle). How to draw a circle in MATLAB GUI figure window? and how to circle handle by MATLAB in realtime?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Answering gui questions is always a heavy task, so you should give us something to play with. [Here is how to draw a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194004/how-to-plot-a-circle/29194105#29194105) for starters.

Comment: Thanks For Reply, I not want axis, and in realtime, circle position also change as per the sensor position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw on an axes -> but you can set the visibility to off.

below you will find an example of how to draw a circle and the position update via the mouse moving.  Its something to get you started...

```
function circleExample
  f = figure;
  ax = axes ( 'parent', f, 'Position', [0 0 1 1] );
  % circle diameter
  d = 2;

  % center of circle.
  c = [10 10];

  % Create position of circle.
  pos = [c-d/2 d d];
  % Create circle via rect command.
  h = rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1]);
  % make sure its looks like a circle.
  axis equal
  % Update some axes properties
  set ( ax, 'visible', 'off', 'XLim', [0 20], 'YLim', [0 20], 'XLimMode', 'manual', 'YLimMode', 'manual' );

  % Add a callback to the figure to update the position when the circle moves
  set ( f, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(a,b)UpdateCirclePos ( ax, h, d ) )
end
function UpdateCirclePos ( ax, h, d )
  cp = get ( ax, 'CurrentPoint' );
  h.Position = [cp(1,1) cp(1,2) d d];
end
```

Comment: How Can i fill circle with colour?

Comment: Set the `FaceColor` property