# Plotting random signal on circle

Tags: matlab, plot, signals, geometry

I have some random signal (for example `sin` signal) with the time scale.

```
t=0:0.1:2*pi
y=sin(t)
plot(t,y)
```

Now I want to draw this signal on this circle. So the time vector actually becomes an envelope of the circle. Envelope of the circle represents "y = 0" in cartesian coordinate system.

Here is an example of what I expect the output to look like:
[image: The example picture of what we want is on this link.]
<sub>(source: [slikomat.com](http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0623/m4r-201506.jpg))</sub>

Thank in advanced!

Comment: What have you tried though? To start with, just plot the circle. Then try add your `y` on and see what happens. I think you'll find you also need to add an `x` random signal too, but you need to at least try it yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "noise" to the radius of the circle, roughly around `r=1`:

```
th = linspace( 0, 2*pi, N ); %// N samples
noise = rand( 1, N ) * .1; %// random noise in range [0..0.1]
r = 1+noise; %// add noise to r=1
figure;
plot( r.*cos(th), r.*sin(th) ); title('noise on circle');
```

An example plot would look like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me allot! I was trying to plot heart rate around the circle envelope. And I did it wit your help!

Answer (score 2):

Based on my previous answer to [**How to plot a circle?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194004/how-to-plot-a-circle/29194105#29194105):

```
%// radius
r = 2;

%// center
c = [3 3];

%// number of points
n = 1000;

%// running variable
t = linspace(0,2*pi,n);

%// noise
noise_frequency_factor = 20;
noise_amplification = 0.1*r;
noise_function = @(a,b,x) a*(sin(b*x) + 1);
noise = noise_function(noise_amplification,noise_frequency_factor,t);

%// circle with noise
x = c(1) + (r+noise).*sin(t);
y = c(2) + (r+noise).*cos(t);

%// draw line
line(x,y)

%// envelope circle
x = c(1) + (r).*sin(t);
y = c(2) + (r).*cos(t);

%// draw line
line(x,y,'color','r')

%// or draw polygon if you want to fill it with color
%// fill(x,y,[1,1,1])
axis equal
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use [`polar`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html):

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
y = .1*sin(t*30); %// amplitude .1 and frequency 30, relative to circle
polar(t, 1+y);
```

[image]

If you want to remove the text generated by `polar`, use

```
delete(findall(gca, 'type', 'text'))
```

[image]