# Matlab - polygon and line intersection

Tags: matlab

Based on [Matlab - Draw angles lines over circle and get the intersecting points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147322/matlab-draw-angles-lines-over-circle-and-get-the-intersecting-points)

I tried the following code that should find the intersecting points and mark them. Unfortunately, it does not work. Do you have an idea how I can solve it?

Script:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

r=1000;

nCircle = 1000;

t = linspace(0,2*pi,nCircle);

xCircle = 0+ r*sin(t);  
yCircle = 0+ r*cos(t); 

pgon = polyshape(xCircle,yCircle ); 

line(xCircle,yCircle );

axis equal;
hold on;

nAngles = 45;
lineLength = r+50;


for angle = 0:nAngles:359
    xLine(1) = 0;
    yLine(1) = 0;
    xLine(2) = xLine(1) + lineLength * cosd(angle);
    yLine(2) = yLine(1) + lineLength * sind(angle);
    plot(xLine, yLine);
    lineseg = [xLine; yLine];
    intersectCoord = intersect(pgon,lineseg);
    scatter(intersectCoord(2,2),intersectCoord(1,2));
end
```

The update script only check the last generated line but it still does not work with intersect:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

r=1000;

nCircle = 1000;

t = linspace(0,2*pi,nCircle);

xCircle = 0+ r*sin(t);  
yCircle = 0+ r*cos(t); 

objectCircle =  rot90([xCircle; yCircle]);

line(xCircle,yCircle);

axis equal;
hold on;

nAngles = 35;
lineLength = r+5;

for angle = 0:nAngles:360
    disp(angle);
    xLine(1) = 0;
    yLine(1) = 0;
    xLine(2) = xLine(1) + lineLength * cosd(angle);
    yLine(2) = yLine(1) + lineLength * sind(angle);
    plot(xLine, yLine);
    lineseg = [xLine; yLine];

end

coefficients = polyfit([xLine(1), xLine(2)], [ yLine(1),  yLine(2)], 1);
a = coefficients (1);
b = coefficients (2);

for xLineCoord = 0:lineLength
    i=xLineCoord+1;
    yLineCoord=a*xLineCoord +b ;
    yLineCoordArray(i, :) = yLineCoord;
    xLineCoordArray(i, :) = i;
end 

objectLine = [xLineCoordArray, yLineCoordArray];
C = intersect(objectLine,objectCircle);
```

Comment: `intersect` does not do what you think it does. Read the docs! `intersect(A,B) returns the data common to both A and B, with no repetitions`. You just need to write code for the intersection.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Any idea how to do it without polyxpoly (I do not have Mapping Toolbox)?

Comment: Yes, line-line intersections are very easy to analytically solve.

Comment: I uploaded an update script with the aim to intersect the two doubles but still get a wrong answer. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You are overwritting a and b every iteration. Please take more than 3 seconds to look at your code.

Comment: True, took it out of the loop. Anyway, the variable C results is 1000 and not the X,Y coordinates of the intersection.

Comment: ah, I can if you want link you to the reason why C is that! :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150024/matlab-polygon-and-line-intersection?noredirect=1#comment89286164_51150024